# Apparent counter-example to Kumagai's derivative free implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

This question refers to the derivative free implicit function theorem from the paper: "An Implicit Function Theorem: Comment" by S. Kumagai (1980 https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF00934117 )

In the set-up of that paper, we take:

- $n=1$, $m=1$,
- $F(x,y)=x^2$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$,
- $x_0=0$, $y_0=0$,
- $A_0=B_0=\mathbb{R}$,
- $H(y)=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then, for all $y\in B_0$, the equation $F(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution given by $x=H(y)$.

Thus, according to the paper's main theorem, there exist open neighbourhoods of $0$, $A_0$ and $B_0$, such that for all $y\in B_0$, the function defined for $x\in A_0$ by $x \mapsto F(x,y)$ is locally one-to-one.

But $F$ is not locally one-to-one at $x=0$! (The restriction of $F$ to any open neighbourhood of $x=0$ is not injective.)

What am I missing?

If this really is a mistake, can it be fixed? Is the proof of the harder direction correct? Are there other derivative free implicit function theorems?